# How can I choose the number of Principal Components?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca

I used PCA algorithm to reduce the number of dimensions. This is my code for dimensional reduction in MATLAB:

```
%Definition of Input Data Matrix
X=[2 13 4 5 4;
   5 14 2 8 5;
   7 8 14 9 8;
   16 5 8 9 22;
   13 24 25 4 44]

% Calculation of Covarian Matrix.
covmat=cov(X)

%Caculation of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors
eigval=eig(covmat)
[eigvec,D]=eig(covmat)

% Sorting of EigenValues and EigenVectors
[eigval,index]=sort(eigval,'descend');
eigvec=eigvec(:,index);
W=eigvec;

%new data by EigenVectors
T=X*W;

%dimension reduction N=your value
TN=X*W(:,1:N);
```

In the last line we must set `N` to the desired number of dimensions. PCA tries to minimize averaged squared projection error and total variation in data can be defined as the average over data saying how far are the training examples are from the origin.

Typically, we choose N to satisfy the following criteria:

[image]

How can calculate this value in matlab to define N ?

More information about PCA can be found [here.](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/14_Dimensionality_Reduction.html)

Comment: Please consult the duplicate.  You are looking at what is known as the variance explained.  In Amro's answer, the first plot generates the variance explained plot.  The horizontal axis is the # of components and the vertical axis is the variance explained.  You would choose the # of components that results in a vertical axis value of 0.99.